Why am I seeing two L1D cache misses in a multithreaded setup during read-modify-store operations?
I have a multithreaded setup where one thread acts as a writer and the other as a reader. The writer performs a read-modify-store operation on a shared std::atomic variable, and the reader continuously reads the same variable to check if the value is updated.
Here is the minimal code example:
Writer Thread:
void writer(std::atomic<size_t>& shared_value, size_t total_writes) {
    bindThreadToCore(0); // Bind writer to core 0
    // PerfMeasure pm(0x151); // L1D cache misses
    size_t writer_local_value = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < total_writes; ++i) {
        // pm.enable();
        for(int j = 1; j < 100; ++j) {
            writer_local_value = shared_value.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
            if(shared_value.compare_exchange_strong(writer_local_value, writer_local_value+1, std::memory_order_relaxed))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        // pm.disable();
        writer_local_value++;

        // Simulate some work
        volatile int waste = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; ++j) {
            ++waste; // Prevent compiler optimizations
        }
    }
}

Reader Thread:
void reader() {
    size_t last_seen_value = 0;
    while (true) {
        size_t current_value = shared_value.load(); // Read
        if (current_value != last_seen_value) {
            last_seen_value = current_value;
            // Perform some operation when value is updated
        }
    }
}

Setup: 
Platform: x86_64 
OS: Ubuntu 
CPU: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900K 
Cache Miss Measurement Tool: perf_event_open 
Using raw counters with event code 0x151, which corresponds to L1D cache misses as documented here.
Observation: 
When the writer performs the read-modify-store operation, I observe two L1D cache misses for the shared_value:
One during shared_value.load() (read). 
Another during shared_value.store() (write). 
However, if I replace the writer's code with a simple shared_value.store() without any prior load, I see only one L1D cache miss.
For example:
void writer_simple() {
    while (true) {
        shared_value.store(42); // Only store
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }
}

In this case, only one cache miss occurs, as expected.
Question: 
Why does the read-modify-store operation in the writer result in two L1D cache misses instead of just one? 
Shouldn't the cache line already be invalidated and fetched during the initial load, and thus no additional miss should occur during the subsequent store?
What causes this discrepancy as MESI protocol should have resulted only one cache miss?
Additional Notes: 
I've tried using different memory consistency models for the std::atomic variable but still observe the same number of cache misses. 
I've ensured that shared_value is aligned to a cache line and there is no false sharing between threads.

What perf event did you count?  My first guess is the writer's load missing in L1d and getting the line in Shared state, and then the store missing and having to do a read-for-ownership to promote from shared to exclusive/modified.  But with the other thread only reading, I don't know why the writer's load would miss.  Maybe if there was false-sharing; the reader writing a global in the same cache line?  (The reader's load only gets Shared). BTW, since you use the default seq_cst memory_order for .store, it will compile to an xchg (because mov+mfence is slower), so that's a second load.

sleep_for(1ms) might be long enough for the core to enter a sleep deep enough to power down L1d cache, leaving all lines invalid when that thread wakes up.  Or for it to be common for that thread to wake up on a different core?  What CPU, and what compiler version/options?  And again, what perf event?  L1d loads?  Or an event that also included L1d store misses?

I am comiling with gcc version 12.2.0 with just pthread flag. My cpu is 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900K. I am using perf with raw counters with event code 0x151 which corresponds to https://perfmon-events.intel.com/index.html?pltfrm=ahybrid.html&evnt=L1D.REPLACEMENT. Also, I've tried with other consistency models but still getting the same number of cache misses. I've also ensured that shared_value is aligned to cache line and false sharing is not present.

Oh, so an anti-optimized (debug) build, -O0 is the default.  Your thread's stack memory should stay hot in cache so there shouldn't be extra cache misses from all the extra loads/stores of local vars.  But even with optimized code there'd be a function call at some point for sleep_for; it almost certainly calls nanosleep in libc so there will be a push on the callstack; that won't inline the syscall instruction and x86 call/ret push and pop the return address.

Are you using PEBS for the counter, to be sure events are associated with the right instruction, not just a nearby instruction?  And/or to have a data address for the event?  Are there other L1D.replacement events that aren't for shared_value which you're not mentioning?

@PeterCordes I've updated writer side code to provide more details. I've tried compiling with O2 option and still getting same results
